# Dynamic type depending of condition Grahpql Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I need to define a field called `user_session` but can be two different types: `AppUserType` or `AgentType` so, I have this:

```
field :user_session, Types::AgentType, null: false
def user_session
  current_user
end
```

How can I say to field if `current_user.is_a?(Agent)` then, take `AgentType` else take AppUserType

I don't know if need more information about this for an answer, just request it, thank you (Sorry for my bad English)

#### Update

I tried to use unions in this way:

```
query_type.rb

field :user_session, Types::MyUnionType, null: false
```

```
my_union.rb

  class MyUnionType < Types::BaseUnion
    possible_types Types::AgentType, Types::AppUserType

    def self.resolve_type(object, context)
      if object.is_a?(Agent)
        Types::AgentType
      else
        Types::AppUserType
      end
    end

  end
```

But does not work for me, I don't know if this is the right way to call the union on field method

Answer (score 1):

A [union type](https://graphql-ruby.org/type_definitions/unions.html) is what you're looking for.

> How can I say to field if current_user.is_a?(Agent) then, take AgentType else take AppUserType

This can be done in the `resolve_type` method, also known as the *type resolver*.

Comment: do you know how is called in the field method? if i call in this way: `field :user_session, Types::MyUnion, null: false`, ruby say something like: "Selector cannot be called on union directly"

Comment: I have updated the question. please check it @kamil

Comment: @JonnathanCarrasco Can you quote the error exactly as it is?

Comment: @JonnathanCarrasco also, can you share your graphql query?

i think your query is wrong, have a look how to query for union types: https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#union-types